# NotifyDataSetChanged() not updating listview after closing alert dialog

Tags: android-studio, notifydatasetchanged

In my adapter class I have created a alert dialog and added a update button to it which allows me to update the items on my list view, it updates my listview but only when I leave the page and return back to it, I have used notifydatasetchanged but it doesn't seem to work, I want it to update on the list view immediately after the dialog closing.

update button

```
viewHolder.btnDisplayUpdate.setText("Update");
        viewHolder.btnDisplayUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                updateCrime(crimes);
            }
        });
```

Update method

```
private void updateCrime(CrimesDelete crimes){
        AlertDialog.Builder popupWindow = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_update, null);
        popupWindow.setView(root);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = popupWindow.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        editLocation = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.editText_location);
        editType = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.editText_type);
        editDescription = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.editText_description);
        editDate = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        editTime = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.editText_rating);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getContext(), R.array.rating, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                       View view, int pos, long id) {
                editRating = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                if (pos==0){
                    editRating = null;
                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        editLocation.setText(crimes.getLOCATION());
        editType.setText(crimes.getTYPE());
        editDescription.setText(crimes.getDESCRIPTION());
        editDate.setText(crimes.getDATE());
        editTime.setText(crimes.getTIME());

        root.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                String location = editLocation.getText().toString().trim();
                String type = editType.getText().toString().trim();
                String description = editDescription.getText().toString().trim();
                String date = editDate.getText().toString().trim();
                String time = editTime.getText().toString().trim();
                String rating = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                DB_CRIME.updateDate(crimes.getID(), location, type, description, date, time, rating);

                loadUpdatedCrimes();
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadUpdatedCrimes() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Crime has been Updated" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps call `notifyDataSetChanged()` directly on the list's adapter object.

Comment: Tried that didn't work